# Is it correct to say that this car moves by electricity?

Tags: prepositions

I know it could also be said by "This car moves with electricity." or "Electricity moves this car." What do you think of this?

Comment: It would be preferable to say "This car is powered by electricity" or "This car moves with electric **power**"

Comment: None of the above.  You could say "the car is powered by electricity".  The only way your sentences would make sense is if the mechanism of movement is something like electrostatic repulsion.  You wouldn't say "this car moves with gasoline" or "gasoline moves this car."

Comment: Why not just say "This is an electric car."? Movement is implied since that is what cars do.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer:

> This car uses electricity.

Or

> This car is electric driven.

Or

> Electricity drives this car.